# Dynamic routing with array of values AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, web, angularjs-routing

I would like to provide a dynamic route with AngularJS and get an array of value, like we would do with GET request parameters : (/?id[]=1&id[]=2..)
I do not know if angular js provides a "clean" way like :

```
/array/of/value/[1,2,3,4]
```

And get the array with ngRoute and $routeProvider :

```
.when("/list/:arrayOfValue", {templateUrl: "./partials/list.html", controller: "ListController"})
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601851/dynamic-routing-with-array-item-in-angularjs-after-filtering-array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ui-router` module, just inject the `$state`, and use `$state.params.arrayOfValue`

```
myModule.controller('myController', ['$state', function($state) {
   var myArray = $state.params.arrayOfValue;
});
```

I tested it, and it's working with array of numbers or string:

```
/array/of/value/[1,2,3,4]
/array/of/value/['test', 45, 'app']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunetly my app isn't based on ui-router. I tryed to include it to my app because this seems relevant related to my problem but my app needs ng-route and its route provider. You might have another solution. I could parse this piece of string by myself.